# Large Search engine DB, being extremely slow

Tags: php, database, performance, mariadb

I run a Large Data base, `~46,704,700 Rows`, and `~7.2 GiB`. And it is dragging my website speed down, what is the best way to speed up the database?

```
You also might need to know:
The Database is on a server that has a 100GB Drive just for the DB
The Database is MariaDB
The Database is on a External Server
The Search engine is written in PHP and I would be happy to share any and all code that I based it off of.
```

Any help will be Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: You have 46 million *tables*? Or rows?

Comment: `~46,704,700 Tables` Tables really? (Sounds like a not so optimal DB design)

Comment: Rows, Sorry that is 100% my bad. Thank you for clearing that up @ceejayoz

Comment: This is a very specific problem. Could be about queries, indexes, the configuration, server capacity or anything. Probably you use a kind of script(open source project)? MariaDB/Mysql must be fine at least till 2 billion rows with good management.

Comment: After asking on IRC I got this answer `show table status;` This (for now) is working.

Comment: In most cases, db speed is related on your data. For optimazation you need a good concept for indexing, caching and query design. Think without more information about the structure and your queries it will be hard to find a solution

Comment: Maybe 40M rows in one table?  (That is feasible for 7.2GiB.)  Now, please provide the SQL that you have identified as the likely culprit.  And the table schema for the table(s) involved.  I ask for those because _most_ "slow" things are caused by a slow query; fixing that may be as simple as adding a composite index or reformulating the query.  If that fails, we will suggest looking at some other aspect.

Comment: Also...  Note that [php] has 1.4M Questions; adding more tags will help draw in more people with relevant expertise.

Comment: Hey, there is one tool that finds slow `MySQL` queries and are able to easily point issues. https://stackify.com/retrace/   **Retrace** shows you how to find slow queries as well as how many times a query has been executed.